# Batch creation of Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to create 1000 Connectors, each one with one task, his own consumer group and unique topic in my Kafka Kubernetes cluster
(My end goal after creating the connectors, is sending a lot of requests to the connectors' topics and measure performances for our implemented connector sink).

Every creation triggers rebalancing across the cluster which "blocks" the Connector RestAPI (returns 409 for everything) and shutting down tasks.

Therefore I have three questions:

1. Is the rebalancing a sort of downtime for the connector (As I said, there are tasks shutting down and restart while rebalancing and one task for connector)?
2. Can I configure the rebalancing schedule?
3. Is there a way of creating Connectors in batches so it would be fast (say creating 100 connectors in less than one second) and won't cause downtime (if the answer for the first question is yes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around the problem would be to start 1000 Connect Clusters (say, via Docker Orchestration), all with one or few Connectors.

---

There isn't a way around the rebalancing. You're adding consumers to the same consumer group, so that'll always rebalance.

Rather than running one task per connector, I would suggest grouping multiple topics/tasks together than share similar configurations, that way you limit how much rebalancing would be done.

Comment: Since I'm using kubernetes, 1000 connect cluster means pods? each with his own zookeeper and brokers?
And regarding your second point, each connector (which has a unique name) is in his own consumer group since - "For sink connectors, the group.id is created programmatically using the prefix connect- and the connector name." - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html

Comment: You can use the same Kafka/Zookeeper cluster for each Connect Cluster. Regarding the second point, the internal topics of Kafka Connect are in the same group unless you are changing those as well

Comment: You mean the state\config\offsets topics? How can I set the internal topics?

Comment: Yes, those topics. When you add new connectors, at least the config topic gets updated, then tasks get redistributed

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to set internal topic (like the config topic) per connector?
Is there a way to create a new config topic for each created connector?

Comment: Not per connector, no, but per container, yes. Thus, as I suggested multiple "clusters" or ReplicaSets, if you will.